# How to use dynamic variables using GraphQL in NEXTjs

Tags: next.js, graphql, thegraph

So I am trying to build an application in which I need to pass the account as queury. How can I achieve this?

My proposed solution (which is not working obviously):

```
let account = '0x74c7b157af4E5418F03eb928DF309cc98CE38E66';  
const GET_ACTIVE_ITEM = gql` 
{
   activeFiles(
      first: 5 
      where: {Account_contains: ${account}}
    ) {
       id
       tokenId
       ipfsHash
       Account
       Privilege
      }
}`
```

Error message I got

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're missing `query`
2. I don't think you can interpolate a variable like that.

Try to put it in a variable in a query like this:

```
const GET_ACTIVE_ITEM = gql` 
query GetActiveFiles($account: String!) {
  activeFiles(
    first: 5 
    where: {Account_contains: $account}
  ) {
    id
    tokenId
    ipfsHash
    Account
    Privilege
  }
}`;
```

And then you can go:

```
let account = '0x74c7b157af4E5418F03eb928DF309cc98CE38E66';

const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_ACTIVE_ITEM, {
      variables: {
        account: account
      },
  });
```

Give this a read:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/

Comment: Thnx mate for the help!!